# IP forwarding - Destination unreachable

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

So, I have the following simple network setup:

Let **A** be the main router at 192.168.0.1 on a 24 prefix network.

Let **B** be a linux device connected to the network at 192.168.0.185.

Let **C** be a second device connected to the network at 192.168.0.146 but instead of having its gateway point to the router (192.168.0.1) it is pointing to device B. That is, all traffic generated at device C goes from device C to device B and finally to the router (device A).

The problem is that despite having already allowed ip forwarding on device B and adding a few iptables to ensure traffic gets forwarded, nothing seems to be happening. Device C can ping device B without any problem, however, when device C tries to send a packet to a public ip or any other ip address in the same subnet, I receive back a "Destination host unreachable" error.

This is the configuration on device B, it is connected to the main router on wlan0:

iptables -S

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

netstat -rn

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.134.203.168  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 rmnet_data0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

ip route list

```
10.134.203.168/30 dev rmnet_data0 proto kernel scope link src 10.134.203.170
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.185
```

When I disable ip forwarding on device B, device C just hangs there waiting for an answer but when I active ip forwarding, device C instantly receives a "Destination host unreachable" error. So that discards ip forwarding as the main issue, I think. The problem probably has to do with iptables and ip routing.

On other linux machines simply allowing ip forwarding did the trick, apparently this one needs some additional configuration.

Does anyone have any idea which command I should run in order for this to work? How should I edit the routing table?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

So I've done what you've requested, now my routing table looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.134.203.168  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 rmnet_data0
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 wlan0
```

Unfortunately the issue still persists...

Is there something that I should change?

Thanks

**UPDATE 2**

I've compared the routing tables to other linux distributions and have copied them. Tried a few more things, but still nothing.

This is the current table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.135.186.32   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 rmnet_data0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

which is the expected one to work well. I guess since I'm doing this on Android 9 then everything is completly different so perhaps it isn't possible unless I modify the entire filesystem which I'm not going to do.

Before on Android 8 this wasn't an issue, I don't know what they've done on the new version.

Comment: There is no default gateway listed in your routing table.

Comment: What address is C trying to reach?

Comment: @RonTrunk just any public ip really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix it!

We have to first clean up iptables, allow ip forwarding, add ip route and finally add the main route.

This can all be done with 4 commands:

```
iptables -F -t filter
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
ip route add default via {gateway}
ip rule add from all lookup main pref 1
```

Thanks everyone for your time

Answer (score 1):

As @yoonix points out, Computer B has no default route.  So it doesn't know where to forward packets to unknown networks.

Comment: I've tried doing that though it still doesn't work... I've updated my question with the new details, thanks.

Comment: I believe I should add another entry with a different destination, such as 0.0.0.0

Comment: Yes a default route destination should be 0.0.0.0 with a mask of 0.0.0.0.  The destination is device A

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've addressed one final thing in my question, though I think what I'm trying to accomplish could simply not be possible on the new android version.